# How can I copy a big file from one Windows machine to another limiting speed transfer?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, speed, network-traffic

Because of traffic reasons I am not able to transfer big files inside my network, unfortunatelly, I need to do such thing everyday.

I usually transfer these files by coping and pasting from my computer to another network drive(\targetIP\targetpath), just like this:

[image]

TIs there any tool, Windows configuration or some technique to limit file speed transfer to 10Mb/s?

PS: I don't want to use FTP or another protocol.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use Robocopy with /IPG switch.

http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html for more info on RoboCopy

Comment: Didn't work for me. Tried W7 and 2012 editions both used 100% bandwidth. The best I could do was use a value of 10000 and all I got were spikes at intervals.

Answer (score 6):

Use Robocopy with a  `/IPG` switch to limit bandwidth. Robocopy comes standard on Windows 7 and Windows 2008 Server

http://yellowtriangle.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/bandwidth-throttling-with-robocopy/

this link includes formula for figuring out maximum speed.

Answer (score 1):

Tried Robocopy but didnt work for me, both W7 and 2012 versions. Used [UltraCopier](https://ultracopier.first-world.info/%20%22UltraCopier) and it worked beautifully, and I could raise and drop the usage as needed while the copy was in progress...