# Reducing Command Priority: Robocopy Slows System

Tags: performance, batch, file-transfer, process, robocopy

How can I prevent Robocopy from slowing other processes to a near standstill?

I have [a Windows 10 batch file](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2020/12/11/hourly-backup/) running Robocopy, once per hour, to mirror one drive and to copy changed files on another drive. Robocopy seems to enjoy high priority: if it has to copy much material, other processes nearly stop.

My batch file puts copies of files into 24 different backup folders, numbered by the hour. I wondered if [Robocopy's monitoring options](https://serverfault.com/questions/55733/the-job-and-monitoring-options-of-robocopy) could be persuaded to copy only a few files at a time, so as to allow other processes to catch their breath. But I didn't see a way to terminate those monitoring options before the end of the hour, instead of running continuously.

I see [the possibility](https://superuser.com/a/1385609/124687) of using `START` to specify process priority. But I don't know how to determine Robocopy's default priority, so as to choose a slightly slower priority. I'm also not sure whether priority is the real culprit, or exactly how a change in priority (via `START` or otherwise) would affect the functioning of a Robocopy command. That is, I don't know exactly what it is about Robocopy that would cause other processes to slow down, when a simple `COPY` command has no such effect.

There is also the concern that using `START` or monitoring could cause my two separate Robocopy commands (i.e., mirroring one drive and copying changed files from the other drive) to run at the same time instead of sequentially, resulting in disk thrashing.

Comment: Does the `/IPG` switch allow limiting speed on drive to drive transfers? Looks like it would help if you were using a network drive... https://superuser.com/questions/701675/how-can-i-copy-a-big-file-from-one-windows-machine-to-another-limiting-speed-tra

Comment: Thanks. I found a suggestion to try /IPG:750 for a transfer rate of about 1Mbps on a network. See e.g., deviousweb.com/2018/01/09/robocopy-throttle-bandwidth. This turned out to be very slow. I found the real culprit: I was using /MT:32 to speed up transfers. Removing the MT option eliminated the problem: Robocopy ran but didn't slow everything else down.